# SQL trigger cutting email after @

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a trigger, that checks if the domain of the email, exists in another table (domain).

Table user:

```
+------------------+ +------------------+
| email            | | domain           |
+------------------+ +------------------+
| Joe@gmail.com    | | gmail.com        |
| Jack@live.com    | | live.com         |
| Berti@outlook.com| |------------------|
|------------------|
```

The trigger is:

```
IF EXISTS ( 
            SELECT 1 
            FROM [USER] AS U INNER JOIN inserted AS I 
            ON U.EMAIL = I.EMAIL
            WHERE REPLACE(RIGHT(U.EMAIL, CHARINDEX('@', U.EMAIL)-2),'_',' ') NOT IN (
                SELECT DOMAIN_NAME
                FROM ALLOWED_DOMAIN
            )
        )
```

The trigger doens't work correctly so i runned the following query:

```
 select REPLACE(RIGHT(U.EMAIL, CHARINDEX('@', U.EMAIL)-2),'_',' '), EMAIL
 from [USER] U
```

Which gives the following result:

```
| unknown        | email            |
+----------------|---------------   |
| gmail.com      | Joe@gmail.com    | 
| ive.com        | Jack@live.com    |
| ti@outlook.com | Berti@outlook.com|
+----------------|------------------|
```

For now it looks like the trigger applies the amount of characters from the 1st record to all records in the table...
How can i fix the trigger so it works multiple row?

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: `RIGHT(U.EMAIL, len(u.email) - CHARINDEX('@', U.EMAIL))` will give the domain part

Comment: as well as reverse without getting the len of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
drop table if exists dbo.Email;


create table dbo.Email (
    email varchar(100)
);


insert into dbo.Email (email)
values ('Joe@gmail.com')
, ('Jack@live.com')
, ('Berti@outlook.com')

select
  RIGHT(U.EMAIL, len(u.email) - CHARINDEX('@', U.EMAIL))
from dbo.Email u
```

Answer (score 2):

this should be the right statement

using reverse and right

```
declare @email as varchar(max) = 'abc@123456.com'

select REPLACE(Right(@email, CHARINDEX('@', reverse(@email))-1),'_',' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are using `CHARINDEX` to find the distance from the beginning of the string and then using that to count from the end of the string in the `RIGHT` function.

You will need to subtract the number from the length of the string like this

```
select REPLACE(RIGHT(U.EMAIL,Len(U.Email) - CHARINDEX('@', U.EMAIL)),'_',' '), EMAIL 
From [User] U
```

Or just

```
select RIGHT(U.EMAIL,Len(U.Email) - CHARINDEX('@', U.EMAIL)), EMAIL
from [USER] U
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUBSTRING`

```
DECLARE @Val NVARCHAR(100) = 'Berti@outlook.com'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Val, CHARINDEX('@', @Val, 0) + 1, 1000) -- outlook.com
```

After `@` character you can return all characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @email varchar(50) = 'Berti@outlook.com'
select SUBSTRING(@email, CHARINDEX('@' ,@email) +1 , Len(@email) -  CHARINDEX(@email,'@'))
```